# How to add datasource to a report in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, report

In VS2008 we have menu Report->Data Sources... which opens "Report Data Sources" from here we can see Project data sources & we can add them into our report by pressing "Add to Report".

but in VS2010 RC there is no such thing like this (no Data Sources... option inside Report menu)

any help?

Answer (score 3):

They [moved it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252085.aspx). It is located in the View menu under Report Data.

Answer (score 0):

Exists one option on the report named Report Data where you can build a New Datasources and DataSets.

Comment: This should be comment not answer.